# DocumentDB - The input name is invalid. Ensure to provide a unique non-empty string less than '255' characters

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to insert data into Azure DocumentDb, however I am getting the following error

```
The input name "123456" is invalid. Ensure to provide a unique non-empty string less than '255' characters.","The request payload is invalid. Ensure to provide a valid request payload."]}
```

I am using the following code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString)))
                {
                    await client.CreateDocumentAsync(documentCollection.DocumentsLink, Document.LoadFrom<Document>(ms));
                }
```

This code appears to be correct, however I have also tried using the docomentCollection.SelfLink and that also fails.

The database and collection have been created and I can verify this through the azure portal, however no data is ever inserted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

DocumentDB treats `id` as a special property, in which it must be a unique non-empty string with less than 255 characters.

In this case, I believe you are creating a document with the `id` as a numeric value:

```
{
  "id": 123456
}
```

You will need to cast the `id` to a string:

```
{
  "id": "123456"
}
```

Comment: Performing a find replace on id and giving it a new name worked a treat.